# CSS - How to add a border color to a css shape

Tags: css, css-shapes

I need to add a border color to a css shape but i don't know how to do that.
I already try with `border` or `border-width` but doesn't work.

This is my code:

```css
.shape
    {
      width: 400px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: green;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
      clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Thank you

Comment: border: 2px solid #000;

Comment: You can add a border, but it will be hidden where you have clipped the div. Is your question about simply adding a border, or adding a border over a clip?

Comment: yes, i need to put the border also in clipped zone. @CalT

Comment: If the duplicate answers don't help, you could try an approach like this: https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/azJWWX

Comment: Do you want this to work in Safari, IE and Edge?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Pseudo-Element

A nice way to do this would be with a pseudo-element like a `:before`

Make exactly the same shape but slightly smaller which holds the main color you want and position it correctly and you get the border you want.

```css
.shape {
  width: 400px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  position: relative;
}

.shape:before {
  content: '';
  width: 398px;
  height: 38px;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
  background: green;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @Stewartside, this code is to apply in bootstrap menu. Right now i'm having a problem. The sub-menus doesn't show because we define fixed height. How can i solve this problem using this shapes? Thank you

Comment: If you can get a demo setup ill look at it but the implementation can be done 100 different ways and I dont know what way youve done it.

Comment: I create a question! If you want to see my problem check this link please.
Thank you. @Stewartside
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44456733/bootstrap-integrate-shape-menu-with-bootstrap-menu

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround is using a pseudo and `transform: skew()`.

`transform: skew()` also has way better browser support than `clip-path` has.

```css
.shape {
  position: relative;
  width: 380px;
  height: 40px;
  background-color: green;
  border: 2px solid red;
  margin-left: 25px;
}

.shape::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: -2px;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  border: inherit;
  background-color: inherit;
  border-right-width: 0;
  transform: skewX(-30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try add this:

```
{
...
border: 1px black solid;
...
}
```

Explain:

```css
.shape
    {
      border: 1px black solid;
      width: 400px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: green;
      -webkit-clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
      clip-path: polygon(5% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 100%);
    }
```

```html
<div class="shape"></div>
```

Comment: _"I already try with border or border-width but doesn't work."_

Comment: Ok. But i want to put border also on left side. @NikitaGoncharov

Comment: Then instead border use : border-left

Comment: @NikitaGoncharov `border` implies borders in all directions, including on the left. That's not gonna work..

Comment: I guess why border dont adding this way - because left side is hidden, we can see this if we inspect element, so i find a way to resolve problem - parent element with necessary color with padding left equals to your expected border-size, just look: https://codepen.io/bennettfeely/pen/azJWWX/